# Why the page html is not Loading in nuxt3js

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt-link

I'm Using Nuxt3 js and when I click nuxt-link java script code is working but the page is not coming till I make refresh
this is navbar code:

```
<template>
  <nuxt-link to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
</template>
```

this is about page:

```
<template>
  <div class="pt-8"><h1>About Page</h1></div>
</template>
```

and this is my default.vue layout:

```
<template>
  <div lang="ar" dir="rtl">
    <Navbar /> <slot />
    <app-footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: We will probably need a [repro] here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your index.vue (EDIT: all files!) in /pages directory. It has to include only ONE root element (components are not considered elements) it means that all your contents have to be wrapped in one element. [more info here](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages#usage)

Answer (score 1):

you have to pu your ```about.vue`` in folder >pages

the first try, u can create Page in folder component and access in your browser..

`localhost:3000/{yourPage}`

Comment: That is not correct, page needs to be in `/pages` folder and also should be wrapped in  `<NuxtLayout>`